# Как записать целое число с помощью unsigned?

Tags: java

Приходится работать с очень большими числами - 19 знаков. Для этого выбрал тип long.
Так же, хотелось бы сделать их беззнаковыми.
Как это сделать?

Почему не работает что-то типа

```
unsigned long parameter = 1234567890123456789;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В джаве нету такого зарезервированного слова, но можно использовать

> UnsignedLong

из
*org.apache.axis.types* или *BigInteger*, примерно так:

```
BigInteger unsigned = new BigInteger(1, input);
```

, но тогда надо будет long конвертировать в байты

Comment: мда... геморно

Comment: @StasOn в чём геморность, и на кой ляд так необходимы unsigned? Разумных версий этой нужды мне пока в голову не приходит.

Да, кроме BigInteger есть ещё BigDecimal.

Answer (score 2):

видимо нужно добавить в конец `L`.
Но в java нет unsigned. Это такой язык.

```
 long parameter = 1234567890123456789L;
```

Comment: аналогов нет?

Comment: аналогов java?
Но если нужны  большие числа, то может использовать [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)?

Comment: @KoVadim BigInteger чем лучше long получается то?

Comment: Только  тем, что можно хранить достаточно большие числа.

Comment: Проблема в том, что нужно хранить беззнаковые...

Comment: а в чем проблема? разница между знаковыми и беззнаковыми - в интерпретации первого бита. В строковом представлении - только то, то может появиться минус.

Comment: > Проблема в том, что нужно хранить беззнаковые...

Ну так не кладите знак и все.

Answer (score 0):

19 знаков укладываются в signed long, зачем вам unsigned?

Ну и long сам по себе это просто 64 бита. Unsigned или не unsigned, это трактовка в операциях. Вам действительно нужны unsigned операции? В jav'e их нет, но есть сторонняя библиотека [UnsignedLong](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedLong.html)

Comment: не укладывается. возьмите к примеру 19 девяток.

Comment: конечно не укладывается! И @KoVadim привел отличный пример
Хотя, на самом деле, проблемы начинаются еще раньше, задолго до 19 девяток.

Comment: Приведите пример Ваших проблем.

Comment: согласен, просчитался.

Comment: @KoVadim, ну, вот скажем приходится иметь дело вот с такими числами:
9223392191315324375
для long уже многовато. 
Сейчас просто изменил тип на String

Comment: это логично. Просто я по памяти точный придел не помню. А говорить о "сильно раньше"... как то не с руки.

Comment: а разве не сильно? по-моему очень даже немало так...